# R Shiny - Error : "Found object is not a position"

Tags: r, shiny

Everything works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39jYO.jpg) when i run the shiny app locally. However when i deploy it, i get an error which says "Warning: Error in : Found object is not a position." and [the app](https://imgur.com/a/rQZi9) does not work. I tried everthing that I find including creating a global.R file, reading the data in ui etc. However it is still the same. Thank you for the help.

Here is the code:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
grindelwald_data <- readRDS("data/data.rds")
server <-shinyServer(
function(input, output,session) {

grindelwald_data$Date<-as.Date(grindelwald_data$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
grindelwald_data$Month <- as.factor(format(as.Date(grindelwald_data$Date),"%m"))
grindelwald_data$Year <- format(grindelwald_data$Date,format="%Y")

annual_mean_precipitation<-aggregate( Precipitation ~ Year , grindelwald_data , sum)
annual_mean_temperature<-aggregate( Temperature ~ Year , grindelwald_data , mean)
annual_mean_discharge<-aggregate( Discharge ~ Year , grindelwald_data , mean)
annual_mean_discharge<-annual_mean_discharge[!(annual_mean_discharge$Discharge<5),]  

output$value <- renderPrint({ input$radio })  



output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  dist <- switch(input$dist,
                 "1" = annual_mean_precipitation$Precipitation,
                 "2" = annual_mean_temperature$Temperature,
                 "3" = annual_mean_discharge$Discharge
  )

  x    <- dist     
  # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
  switch(input$dist,
         "1" = updateSliderInput(session, "bins", min=1,max=100,step= 1),
         "2" = updateSliderInput(session, "bins",min=0.01,max=0.7,step= 0.01),
         "3" = updateSliderInput(session, "bins",min=0.01,max=2,step= 0.01)
  )

  switch(input$dist,
         "1" = ggplot(annual_mean_precipitation, aes(x=x))+
           geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=input$bins,colour="white", fill="#56B4E9") +
           geom_density(alpha=.2,colour="#CC79A7",size=1, fill="#FF6666")+
           labs(title="Histogram of the  Annual Mean Precipitation with Density",x="Precipitation (mm)",y="Density"),

         "2" = ggplot(annual_mean_temperature, aes(x=x))+
           geom_histogram(aes(x=x,y=..density..),binwidth=input$bins,colour="white", fill="#F0E442") +
           geom_density(alpha=.2,colour="#CC79A7",size=1, fill="#FF6666")+
           labs(title="Histogram of the  Annual Mean Temperature with Density",x="Temperature (C)",y="Density"),
         "3" = ggplot(annual_mean_discharge, aes(x=x))+
           geom_histogram(aes(x=x,y=..density..),binwidth=input$bins,colour="white", fill="#0072B2") +
           geom_density(alpha=.2,colour="#CC79A7",size=1, fill="#FF6666")+
           labs(title="Histogram of the  Annual Mean Discharge with Density",x="Discharge (m3/s)",y="Density")
    )
  })

 }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
ui<-fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Histogram-Luetschine River"),
radioButtons("dist", label = "",
           choices = list("Precipitation" = 1, "Temperature" = 2,    "Discharge" = 3), 
           selected = 1),


sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of Bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 100,
              value = 17)
),


mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Your radio buttons give you a numeric value, yet your switch has the numbers quoted, as a character.  What happens when you either quote the radio button values or unquote the switch?

Comment: It gives me the same error when I change them. I was thinking that it was about uploading the rds data file, however I can see the file in the shinyapps server.

Comment: Is the folder having rds-file named `data` in shinyapps server ? (just to be sure)

Comment: Yes, It's name is "data".

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the density plot in histogram causes the error. It works fine without the density plot.